# How to pass data between a ViewController and a subview ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController called VCA in which will add a subview VCB. This VCB is a xib generated file that asks for more specific user input by allowing the user to tap a few buttons. What i am having trouble with is determining how i am to pass the values that the user has selected back to VCA. Any help would be great

Comment: Have you tried to create a protocol?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most flexible approach is to create a `@protocol` that viewControllerA will adopt, add a delegate to viewControllerB, and when you initialize viewControllerB, do something in the form:

```
viewControllerB.delegate = viewControllerA
```

In viewControllerB, invoke that protocol:

```
self.delegate.doSomething()
```

By using a `protocol`, you can pass data without tying the two classes together ; there are a few good locations to set the delegate after creating viewControllerB, such as after its creation or prior a segue.

Comment: Thanks For Your Help @SwiftArchitect!

Comment: One More Thing, attributes in viewControllerA become nil after i go about this process. Do you have any thought as to why? Is it my viewDidLoad()?

Comment: This is a different question which I would gladly answer. Please open a different question, put a link to it in a comment, and make sure you post some code!

Answer (score 0):

You could easily create a singleton to share data between your View Controllers. Luckily, it's very simple in Swift.

Like so:

```
class MySingleton() {
     static let sharedData = MySingleton()
     var aVariable: Int = 4         

     init() {}
}
```

You can then invoke the singleton anywhere with:

`let ms = MySingleton.sharedData`

and call properties with:

`var newVar = ms.aVariable`